# IHP - How to use Select Inputs with Nullable Enums in HSX Forms?

Tags: ihp

Given an enum:

```sql
CREATE TYPE CONTENT_TYPE AS ENUM ('video', 'article', 'audio');
```

How should I update the my HSX Form `selectField` to support `Maybe ContentType`?

```hs
  formFor subscription [hsx|
    {selectField #contentType allContentTypes}
|]
    where
      allContentTypes = allEnumValues @ContentType
```

The `CanSelect` instance is defined as follows:

```hs
instance CanSelect (Maybe ContentType) where
    type SelectValue (Maybe ContentType) = Maybe ContentType
    selectValue (Just value) = Just value
    selectValue Nothing = Nothing
    selectLabel (Just groupType) = tshow contentType
    selectLabel Nothing = "none selected"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CanSelect instance looks correct. The list of `allContentTypes` should have a type of  `[Maybe ContentType]`. You can wrap the content types with a `Just` constructor by mapping it over the list: e.g.  `fmap Just allContentTypes` and passing the wrapped list to `selectField`.